# Accesing variable from an inner class in java

Tags: java, mouseevent, inner-classes, mouselistener, anonymous-inner-class

I want to access `i` from `mouseClicked` method. Can Anyone help me out on this?

Here is my code fragment -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        JLabel jl = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
        jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {

                        addAnEventToLabel(i); //Error 1
            }
        });
    }
```

Error 1 - local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final (Showing in IDE) 
but No Runtime or Compliletime Exceptions.

Comment: yes the error message says it. maybe you can assign the value of i to a local final variable and then access that

Comment: @Jack yeah i have created a local final variable. Now I can access that.

Comment: @JackFlamp can you explain me why there are no Runtime or Compile Time Exceptions for this?

Comment: see gperches answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    final int tmpI = i;
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
    jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {

                    addAnEventToLabel(tmpI);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice, we wrote the same thing at the same time. this must be the solution :)

Comment: It Worked. Thanks Bro. Want to learn more about Inner Classes in java.

Comment: @gpeche why there are no Runtime or Compile Time Exceptions for this my code?

Comment: @Nazeer That is a compilation error, it goes against the language rules so the compiler just refuses to make an executable out of it. Exceptions are used for situations when the compiler cannot know if the program fails or not, so it cannot refuse to compile the source.

Comment: Compilation Errors? Interesting..  Thanks man. I will do more research on that

Comment: @Nazeer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3: `Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted. `